# Mockk - MockKException when testing password against regex

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockk

I've just started to do Unit testing in Kotlin using Mockk.
I'm trying to test the following function:

```
    fun evaluatePredicate(regEx: String, passwordInserted: String) : Boolean {
        return passwordInserted.matches(regEx.toRegex())
    }
```

My test look like this:

```
    @Test
    fun evaluatePredicate_shouldContainLowerCase_trueExpected() {

        //given
        val regEx = ".*[a-z]+.*" //lower case
        val password = "password"

        every { password.matches(regEx.toRegex()) } returns true
        every { SUT.evaluatePredicate(regEx, password) } returns true

        //when
        val evaluate = password.matches(regEx.toRegex())
        val result = SUT.evaluatePredicate(regEx, password)

        //then
        assertEquals(evaluate, result)
    }
```

But I'm getting :

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.
```

at line:

```
every { password.matches(regEx.toRegex()) } returns true
```

I've tried to use Mockk Matcher `any()` instead of `matches(regEx.toRegex())` but nothing changed.

I'm not sure if I'm using the right tools for the job here.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: As long as I know you should be able to stub calls inside every only over objects created with mockk (a mock) or spyk (a spy).